# SQL Query Count Instances a Column Type Appears

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble figuring out what appears to be an easy query, I haven't done this in awhile.. any help is appreciated.

I have 2 columns: One that holds the state and one that holds a user type

EX:

```
IL  Type 1 
IL  Type 2 
IL  Type 1 
GA  Type 1
```

How do I write a query that lists each state once and how many times Type 1 appears for the corresponding state?

So the results would look like:

```
IL  2 
GA  1
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the data (`where type='Type 1'`), group it (`group by state`) and apply an aggregate (`count(*)`):

```
select state, count(*) 
from table 
where type = 'Type 1'
group by state
```

Answer (score 0):

Just by using a `COUNT()` and `WHERE` clause:

```
Select    State, Count(*) Count
From      Table
Where     UserType = 'Type 1'
Group By  State
```